# Hidding source control files within Visual Studio's solution tree

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

We use Visual Studio 2008 and Surround SCM for source control. SCM drops files into each directory named ".MySCMServerInfo" which are user specific data files that shouldn't be checked into source control.  They are similar to the .scc files dropped by Visual Source Safe.  We also have several WAPs (Web Application Projects) that we develop.  All these .MySCMServerInfo files show up in the solution tree and the Pending Checkins window when they should not.  There has to be some way to force VS to ignore files of a given extension because it ignores .scc files.  How do I get VS to ignore .MySCMServerInfo files within a WAP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have new information about this issue. Setting the hidden bit on .MySCMServerInfo file causes Surround SCM to loose track of the modification state for files. It starts thinking files are out-of-date when they are not, and it always attemps to get new versions.

Instead, set this registry key if you're using Visual Studio 2008:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Packages\
{8FF02D1A-C177-4ac8-A62F-88FC6EA65F57}\IgnorableFiles\.MySCMServerInfo]
```

Set this registry key if you're using Visual Studio 2005:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\8.0\Packages\
{8FF02D1A-C177-4ac8-A62F-88FC6EA65F57}\IgnorableFiles\.MySCMServerInfo]
```

These will tell Visual Studio to not display .MySCMServerInfo files within the Solution tree and the Pending Checkins view.

Comment: I was unable to get this to work in VS 2010, granted nobody should be using website projects, but can someone confirm this still works?

Answer (score 0):

Using the file system hidden bit should work.

Comment: I also found this work-around. From my web application project root, search for all .MySCMServerInfo files, select, and set their hidden attributes. They no longer show up in the solution tree or the pending checking list. However, It has to be redone whenever SCM gets a new .MySCMServerInfo file.

Answer (score 0):

Late Answer but hopefully useful to others.

I began experiencing this problem when using Visual Studio 2015 with the new ASP.Net 5 Project templates. (I presume this is because the new templates automatically include everything in the folder rather than only showing the things that are listed in the project file).

Showing these files in the Solution explorer change be prevented by right clicking the file and selecting "Hide from Solution Explorer" but this didn't prevent SCM from including them in the Pending Check-ins Window.

The correct way to deal with this problem is:

1. Select the file(s) in Solution Explorer
2. Select the File > Source Control > Exclude from Source Control

[Reference](http://www.seapine.com/knowledgebase/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=751)

---

***NOTE:***  Right Click in the Solution Explorer DOESN'T have this option.